# Экспорт и импорт данных с SQLite Android в таблицу Excel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite

Вообще более или менее способы всё что знаете только на котлин , пробовал `Apache POI` но он не работает. Просто инфы мало по котлину.

Дополнение по просьбе :
Проблема такова : у меня есть база данных sqlite локальная, моё приложение просто сохраняет данные в неё про книги в формате  : имя, автор, жанр.
Я хочу чтобы пользователь попользовавшись определённое время  смог данные с этой бд экспортировать . Очень хочется что бы это был формат эксель.
Так же и с импортом, тип человек мог импортировать подогнанную таблицу эксель в бд.
Пробовал `Apache POI` но  у меня когда путь указываю не находит name и активити не запускается :

`val output = FileOutputStream("(name)./test.xlsx")`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы же используете Room Database, верно?

Comment: я делаю не через room а напрямую через MyDataBaseHelper(знаю что вариант не из лучших но я решил сразу попробовать это)